# Autocomplete for textbox Control under HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, model-view-controller

I have a Html table(instead of Grid control I used HTML table) having multiple rows with one drop down and one textbox control.I want auto complete function for that text box.I implemented the following code for auto complete but it is firing for only first row.The rows are added Dynamically (in jquery) its not workig for those rows.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover datatable-highlight" id="tWDE_Items">
   <thead>
     <tr>                                 
        <th style="display:none">ItemId</th>                                
        <th>Item Name</th>                                  
        <th>UOM</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach (var Item in Model.Data_Wde_ItemGrid)
      {
       <tr class="datarow">                                                                   
          <td style="display:none">@Item.Item_Id</td>
          <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Item.Item_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) </td>
          <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Item.UOM_Id, new SelectList(Item.UOMDetails, "UomId", "UomName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "UomId" })</td> 
        </tr>
       }
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

And Jquery code which I tried is as follows.

```
$(function () {
$('#Item_Item_Name').autocomplete({

    source: function (request, response) {
        debugger;
        var param = { ItemName: $('#Item_Item_Name').val() };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/WDE/GetAutoCompleteItemList",
            data: JSON.stringify(param),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        val: item.split('÷')[0],
                        label: item.split('÷')[1]

                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
    change: function (e, i) {
        if (i.item) {

        }
        else {
            $('#Item_Item_Name').val('');
            $('#Item_Item_Id').val('');
        }
    },
    select: function (e, i) {
        debugger;
        $('#Item_Item_Name').val(i.item.label);
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(2).html(i.item.val);

    },
    minLength: 1
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying

> having multiple rows with one drop down and one textbox control. I want auto complete function for that text box

and I'm also seeing

```
$('#Item_Item_Name').autocomplete(...
```

Are you giving the same id to every textbox? If so, that will not work. Ids have to be unique. Jquery will assume you have only 1 and fire/listen to events only for that 1 textbox.

Consider rewriting your JS using classes for the textbox instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brother..@Ray. But all other events are firing like `change` , `Keydown` and `KeyUp` except `autocomplete`.

Comment: ok.. I would still suggest using classes. From your code it doesn't look like the id is unique

Comment: Or are you saying that there are multiple rows but only 1 textbox?

Comment: No Brother. Each row have one textbox.